# Split [realm] tag

Tags: discussion

The tag [realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realm) is overloaded with the following meanings:

- An authentication realm (180 uses). This is the meaning written in the tag wiki.
- A mobile database (20 uses). This meaning is always tagged [objective-c] or [ios].

There is also a tag [realm.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realm.io) that refers to the mobile database (13 uses).

I suggested the authors of the Realm database to use [realm.io] as tag  because http://realm.io it's also the host name of their project, but [they replied](https://twitter.com/realm/status/512994608041955328) that they prefer to keep using [realm].

I can think of two choices:

1. realm, realm.io: Current popular usage, conflicting with Realm's author wishes.
2. security-domain, realm: The first is the proper name for a J2EE authentication realm.

**What tag name is best, whatever users choose (1), or a more precise name that respect everyone's wishes (2)?**

Note that the second also sets apart J2EE uses from the general concept of user/password/roles. However, the Realm database is still mixed with other uses of the term realm.

---

**Update**

“realm” is a popular synonym for “security domain”, which is defined in the chapter Security Architecture of the Java EE spec.

> Security Policy Domain A security policy domain, also referred to as a
>   **security domain**, is a scope over which a common security policy is
>   defined and enforced by the security administrator of the security
>   service. A security policy domain is also sometimes referred to as a
>   **realm**. This specification uses the security policy domain, or security
>   domain, terminology.

If you search for "[[realm] -[jetty] -[weblogic] -[tomcat] -[tomcat7] -[glassfish] -[glassfish-3] -[spring]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realm+-jetty+-weblogic+-tomcat+-tomcat7+-glassfish+-glassfish-3+-spring)", results go down to 78 from 187, meaning, there are 109 uses of it.

Comment: Thou dareth to split thy realm!?

Comment: Should SO care that Realm prefers the tag to stay like it is, even if that creates confusion in the tag?

Comment: I'm disappointed that I had a five year old question about Tomcat realms edited to remove the realm tag because it's been hijacked by some database.

Answer (score -1):

Tim from Realm here. It seemed pretty clear to us that the “authentication” meaning constitutes a *meta tag*, which is explicitly discouraged by SO. It clearly [passes the two conditions used to identify a meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

1. **it can’t work as the only tag on the question** since it applies only to a vague concept, that has very different implementations across products & features
2. **it means different things to different people** (and in fact was used in very different contexts & products!)

Since SO’s has been very clear about [meta-tags being explicitly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), we would like to keep using realm as a non-meta tag to designate the realm database (especially since 2/3rd of questions on that tag in the past 2 months were already about the database and not about anything relating to authentication).

Comment: Maybe renaming the tag to [realm-database] should be more appropriated. "realm" as term isn't very descriptive what the question is about.

Comment: I edited the question to suggest security-domain, which is not a meta-tag, instead realm-authentication. As Braiam said, I don't think of realm as very descriptive, but I'm all to keep everyone happy and removing java-ee from the mix reduces a lot the confusion.

Comment: @Jano: a lot of questions on the tag seem to be talking about Oracle, LDAP, Glassfish and other instances of a realm concept that are not strictly related to J2EE’s security domains. It’s my current impression that non database-related activity on the tag is caused by people typing random related words in the tags of their questions, which implies the solution isn’t to find a replacement tag for their use-case, but instead but to educate people about using common words in their tags.

Comment: @Braiam: we were actually considering sponsoring the tag for the same reason (to signify its meaning — the way Google is sponsoring the Android tag), but didn’t want to discourage competing uses at the moment — it really doesn’t bother us that much to see random authentication questions on the tag :D

Comment: I downvoted this because you are are basically saying "the tag is ambiguous but we think it is ok for our product".  Your declaration doesn't make the tag unambiguous.  If the tag means multiple things then it mean multiple things, and you should select another tag as @Braiam suggested.

Comment: However, once the tag is cleaned up, making [realm] and synonym of [realm-database] (or whatever tag you choose) would probably be appropriate.

Comment: @psubsee2003 We’d definitely consider moving to another tag but it seemed to us that using common words for established projects was OK, judging by Google using just [android] even though one could expect that tag would be used for other topics on SO. What is the threshold here? We only came out 2 months ago but have ≥20,000 users already, and generate 2/3rds of the activity on the [realm] tag. (btw, the community’s guidance here is greatly appreciated!)

Comment: @timanglade I'm just offering my opinion here... but when you are dealing with a tag that could mean more than one thing, people are going to use it incorrectly, regardless of what anyone wants or says in the wiki.  Look at the tag currently.  No where does it reference your project, but yet people use it incorrectly for your project.  The current "intended" usage is bad but just changing the wiki is not going to fix it.  The proper fix would be to change the tag name to make sure it is clear what the tag is for.  Then apply a tag synonym to [realm] to point to the most popular usage.